# Complete Intersection ideal whose initial ideal is not even Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals, monomial-order

I am trying to find an example, such a example is asked in exercise 3.3 
of the book Monomial Ideals (Herzog & Hibi).

I would like to find a graded ideal $I\subset k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ which is complete intersection, but $\mbox{In}_<(I)$ is not even Cohen-Macaulay
(for some monomial order $<$).

I would be happy with any hint.

PS: I'm trying to find a example using Singular and Macaulay2, but until to now I got nothing .

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312686/complete-intersection-ideal-for-which-mboxin-i-is-not-even-cohen-macaula

Comment: Such examples are standard. Consider $I=(X^2,XY+Z^2)$ and lex.

Comment: Thank you @user26857 !